# setTimeout window.open can't take this.href

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to open the href onMouseOver after 3000ms. But it just popups a blank window. What am I missing?

HTML:

```
<a href="../cc2b/myrec.html" onMouseOver="Popup = setTimeout('openwindow(this.href)',3000);" onMouseOut="clearInterval(Popup)">My Rec</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
var Popup = null;

function openwindow()
{
    var win = window.open()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*(OK, first off, you need to supply a URL to `window.open()`, otherwise it doesn't know what page to open to.  Aside from that:)*

When you do a `setTimeout()` the value of `this` is reset in the delayed code.

A quick fix is to extract the URL immediately, and then pass a function into `setTimeout()` that can use the variable.

```
<a href="../cc2b/myrec.html"
        onMouseOver="var popupUrl = this.href; Popup = setTimeout(function(){openwindow(popupUrl)}), 3000);"
        onMouseOut="clearInterval(Popup)">
    My Rec
</a>
```

However, a cleaner solution would be to minimise the code in `onMouseOver` by setting a timeout in the `openhoverpopup` function:

```
<a href="../cc2b/myrec.html"
        onMouseOver="openhoverpopup(this.href)"
        onMouseOut="clearhoverpopup()">
    My Rec
</a>
<script>
    var popupTimeout = null;
    function openhoverpopup(url) {
        popupTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            window.open(url);
        }, 3000);
    }
    function clearhoverpopup() {
        clearTimeout(popupTimeout);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the URL from the element that triggered the mouseover event with either `event.target` or `event.srcElement` for older IE browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/b42pr/1

#### HTML

```
<a href="theURL" onmouseover="popURL()">Hover</a>
```

#### JavaScript

```
function popURL() {
    var url = event.target.href || event.srcElement.href;
    console.log("Open URL: " + url);
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.open(url);
    }, 3000)
}
```

Comment: Sounds like awesome with pipe and stuff :) lemme try it and i'll get back to u if it works..

Answer (score 0):

`this.href` is undefined, I think you're looking for `window.location.href`:

```
> this.href
  undefined
> window.location.href
  "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981172/settimeout-window-open-cant-take-this-href"
```

Also, your function

```
function openwindow()
{
    var win = window.open()
}
```

Takes no parameters and opens nothing. Change it to

```
function openwindow(target)
{
    var win = window.open(target)
}
```

Be careful though, most pop-up blockers will block this kind of window.

Comment: I think OP is looking to take the URL from the link, not the current URL of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the href outside of the string:

```
<a href="../cc2b/myrec.html" onMouseOver="Popup = setTimeout('openwindow(' + window.location.href + ')',3000);" onMouseOut="clearInterval(Popup)">My Rec</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, as Doorknob says, this should be window.location.href